# hibernate jpa application suspends everytime I want to run it

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1, suspend

I'm using Hibernate 5.2 with JPA 2.1 Library.Every time I want to run my application it doesn't stop - I have to stop it manually because it's still working. Records are being saved to the database correctly. These are my project files:

---

### Main.java

---

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testjpa");
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
            Kraj country = new Kraj();
            country.setNazwa("ExampleCountry");
            em.persist(country);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

}
```

**

### peristence.xml

**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="testjpa">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>bazafilmow.model.Aktor</class>
    <class>bazafilmow.model.Film</class>
    <class>bazafilmow.model.Gatunek</class>
    <class>bazafilmow.model.Kraj</class>
    <class>bazafilmow.model.Rezyser</class>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****"/>
      <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

### Output

---

```
run:
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:06 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: testjpa
    ...]
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:06 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.12.Final}
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:06 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:06 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb]
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****}
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:06 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:07 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@45cff11c] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Jan 03, 2018 11:23:07 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

And it suspends at this moment, there is no BUILD SUCCESSFULL information.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with this, so the problem is elsewhere. Possibly in the entities. Also since you're using Hibernate 5.2 you should change the JPA version in the xml to 2.1 like this `<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">`

Answer (score 0):

i had a same problem after changing the version it works for me.

Comment: This should post as a comment.